Uniform ellipticity Proposition
We consider equations of the form
$$
F\left(\nabla^2 u(x), x\right)=f(x)
$$
where $x \in \Omega$ and $u$ and $f$ are functions defined in a bounded domain $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. $F(M, x)$ is a real valued function defined on $\mathcal{S} \times \Omega$, where $\mathcal{S}$ is the space of real $n \times n$ symmetric matrices. We assume that $F$ and $f$ are continuous.

Note: $N\in \mathcal{S}$ can be uniquely decomposed into $N^+,N^-\geq0$ with $N^+N^-=0$ and $N=N^+-N^-$.

The definition of uniform ellipticity is as follows:

Definition. $F$ is uniformly elliptic if there are two positive constants $\lambda \le\Lambda$ such that for any $M\in \mathcal{S}$ and $x\in \Omega$
$$\lambda \|N\| \le F(M+N,x)-F(M,x)\le \Lambda \|N\|,\quad N\ge0$$
where
$$\|N\|=\sup _{|x|=1}|Nx|,$$
which equals to the maximum eigenvalue of $N$ whenever $N\ge0.$


Question:
How to prove the following:

Proposition. $F$ is uniformly elliptic if and only if $$F(M+N,x)\le F(M,x)+\Lambda\|N^+\|-\lambda\|N^-\|$$ for any $M,N \in \mathcal{S}$ and $x\in \Omega$.


If we have the statement from the lemma, rearranging gives
$$
F(M+N,x)- F(M,x)\le\Lambda\|N^+\|-\lambda\|N^-\|
$$
I thought about using the triangle inequalities which hold for the norm
$$
\|N\|=\|N^+-N^-\|\leq \|N^+\|+\|N^-\|
$$
but I do not get anywhere.

Source: Lemma 2.2 in Caffarelli, L. A., & Cabré, X. (1995). Fully nonlinear elliptic equations (Vol. 43). American Mathematical Soc..

The problem now is

Given $$F(M+N,x)- F(M,x)\le\Lambda\|N^+\|-\lambda\|N^-\|$$ for any $M,N\in\mathcal S$, prove that $$\lambda \|Q\| \le F(P+Q,x)-F(P,x)\le \Lambda \|Q\|$$ for any $P,Q\in\mathcal S$ and $Q\ge 0$.

Set $M=P+Q$ and $N=-Q$, where $Q\ge 0$. Then,
\begin{align}
F(P,x)- F(P+Q,x)&\le\Lambda\|(-Q)^+\|-\lambda\|(-Q)^-\| \\
F(P,x)- F(P+Q,x)&\le\Lambda\|Q^-\|-\lambda\|Q^+\| \\
F(P,x)- F(P+Q,x)&\le -\lambda\|Q\|\qquad \text{because $Q\ge0$} \\
\lambda\|Q\|&\le F(P+Q,x)-F(P,x)
\end{align}
thus the lower bound is proved. The upper bound can be proved much more easily by just substituting in $M=P$ and $N=Q\ge 0$.

For the other direction, we need

Given $$\lambda \|Q\| \le F(P+Q,x)-F(P,x)\le \Lambda \|Q\|$$ for any $P,Q\in\mathcal S$ where $Q\ge 0$, prove that
$$F(M+N,x)- F(M,x)\le\Lambda\|N^+\|-\lambda\|N^-\|$$ for any $M,N\in\mathcal S$.

Proof:
\begin{align}
&F(M+N,x)- F(M,x) \\
&=F(M-N^-+N^+,x)- F(M,x) \\
&=F(M-N^-+N^+,x)-F(M-N^-,x)+F(M-N^-,x)- F(M,x) \\
\end{align}
Consider the first two terms,
$$F((M-N^-)+N^+,x)-F(M-N^-,x)\le \Lambda||N^+||$$
For the last two terms,
\begin{align}
&F(M-N^-,x)- F(M,x) \\
&=F(M-N^-,x)- F((M-N^-)+N^-,x) \\
&=-\bigg(F((M-N^-)+N^-,x)-F(M-N^-,x)\bigg) \\
&\le -\lambda||N^-||
\end{align}
Adding them gives the desired conclusion.

This is only one direction right?

Why does $Q^-$ vanish? How does $Q\geq 0$ imply that?

@calculatormathematical I've just added the other direction.

@calculatormathematical $Q^-$ is always zero for non-negative $Q$. This is because you can trivially write $Q=Q+O$ (where $O$ is the zero matrix) and $QO=O$. As you've noticed, such decomposition is unique, thus $Q^+=Q$, $Q^-=O$.

@calculatormathematical Alternatively, it's more common to think of $|Q^-|$ as the absolute value of the smallest (most negative) eigenvalue of $Q$. When $Q\ge 0$, all its eigenvalues are non-negative, and thus $|Q^-|$ is taken to be zero in this case.
